# How to store the results of a stored procedure without requiring a distributed transaction?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a remote stored procedure that i am running:

```
EXECUTE Contoso.Frob.dbo.Grobber @StartDate='20140513', @EndDate='20140518'
```

and this remote stored procedure returns a rowset:

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName    StartDateTime            EndDateTime
----------  --------------  -------------            -----------------------
619         Guyer, Kirsten  2014-05-13 19:00:00.000  2014-05-13 19:00:00.000
...
```

Excellent. Perfect. Good. Sweet.

Now that i have these results, i need to store them in a table. Any kind of table. I don't care what kind of table:

- physical table
- temporary table
- global temporary table
- table variable

I just need them stored so that i can process them. The problem is that when i try to insert the results into a table, whether it be:

- a physical table

  ```
  INSERT INTO EmployeeSchedule
  EXECUTE Contoso.Frob.dbo.Grobber @StartDate='20140513', @EndDate='20140518'
  ```
- temporary table

  ```
  INSERT INTO #EmployeeSchedule
  EXECUTE Contoso.Frob.dbo.Grobber @StartDate='20140513', @EndDate='20140518'
  ```
- a global temporary table

  ```
  INSERT INTO ##EmployeeSchedule
  EXECUTE Contoso.Frob.dbo.Grobber @StartDate='20140513', @EndDate='20140518'
  ```
- a table variable

  ```
  INSERT INTO @EmployeeSchedule
  EXECUTE Contoso.Frob.dbo.Grobber @StartDate='20140513', @EndDate='20140518'
  ```

SQL Server *insists* (nay, **demands**) that it begin a *distributed transaction*:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "Contoso" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".
>   Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 41
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "Contoso" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

### Why not just...

Now, making changes to the `Contoso` server is not an option. Why? Doesn't matter. Pretend that Jack Bauer will make an appearance and Guantanamo anyone who tries to modify Contoso. This means i cannot enable or reconfigure MSDTC on `\\Contoso`.

### Did you try using `READ UNCOMMITTED`?

Yes.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
INSERT INTO @EmployeeSchedule 
EXECUTE wclnightdb.NGDemo.dbo.tbtGetSchedule @StartDate, @EndDate
```

The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.

And:

```
INSERT INTO #EmployeeSchedule 
WITH (NOLOCK)
EXECUTE wclnightdb.NGDemo.dbo.tbtGetSchedule @StartDate, @EndDate
```

Sorry. No nolock. Nolock is a no no:

> Msg 1065, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   The NOLOCK and READUNCOMMITTED lock hints are not allowed for target tables of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE statements.

### I always could give up on SQL Server

If i were doing this in a programming environment, it would be fairly easy to fix:

```
using (IDataReader rdr = ADOHelper.Execute(conn, "EXECUTE Contoso.Frob.dbo.Grobber @StartDate='20140513', @EndDate='20140518'")
{
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
       InsertRowIntoTable(conn, rdr);
   }
}
```

Although that would require me to create a binary, ship it, and schedule it. I'm looking for the option that works with SQL Server (so SQL Agent can schedule the job).

### Bonus Reading

- [SET REMOTE_PROC_TRANSACTIONS (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178549.aspx)
- [How do I use the results of a stored procedure from within another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861187/how-do-i-use-the-results-of-a-stored-procedure-from-within-another?lq=1)
- [How can one iterate over stored procedure results from within another stored procedure....without cursors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149132/how-can-one-iterate-over-stored-procedure-results-from-within-another-stored-pro)

Comment: you can't change the procedure and have it return an output variable of type TABLE?

Comment: use C# in SQL SERVER, enable the .Net framework.

Comment: how bout creating a function in SQL server that calls the stored procedure?

Comment: a very good well formed question, sorry I can't help.

Comment: @TMcKeown You're not even *allowed* to call a stored procedure inside a function.

Comment: well that sucks.  I stay away from functions as you can tell..

Comment: @TMcKeown They're useful as long as you be sure to **never** call them per-row; ensuring that they're only called once during a T-SQL statement.

Answer (score 3):

> SQL Server insists (nay, demands) that it begin a distributed
>   transaction:

If you can't configure your servers to use distributed transactions for whatever reason, you can tell it not to.

```
USE [master]
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
    @server   = N'Contoso', 
    @optname  = N'remote proc transaction promotion', 
    @optvalue = N'false'
GO
```

Or in SSMS GUI:
[image: linked server properties]

I don't know all implications of turning off this option, but at least now my `INSERT ... EXEC [LinkedServer]...` works.

Answer (score 1):

Two options to try would be:

1. Since you already have a Linked Server set up, use it with [OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx), as in:
    `SELECT column1, column2 FROM OPENQUERY(Contoso, 'EXECUTE Frob.dbo.Grobber @StartDate=''20140513'', @EndDate=''20140518''')`
2. If the returned columns will remain consistent, create a SQLCLR Table-Valued Function. This assumes that the remote proc is Read-Only (i.e. SELECT-only). But unlike T-SQL functions, SQLCLR functions *can* execute Stored Procedures using the connection string "Context Connection = True;" as long as the Stored Procedure is SELECT-only (i.e. does not change the state of the DB through DML, DDL, etc).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

-- Either create a job that runs your remote sql via a SQLSMD command, or just run something like this:
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -S Server\SQLSERVERDEV2005 -i"c:\DML.sql"'
(It might be easier with a job because you can modify the job step easily via sp_update_jobstep to get the right values in for your parameters)

-- Output the result of the sqlcmd into a file

-- Load the file into a table via bulk import.